# php too slow on localhost running simple math test

Tags: php, performance

I was running this simple math test on my localhost:

```
$r = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

$result = FALSE;

while($result == FALSE){
    if(
        $r[0] + $r[1] - $r[2] == 4 &&
        $r[3] - $r[4] + $r[5] == 8 &&
        $r[6] * $r[7] - $r[8] == 8 &&
        $r[0] + $r[3] - $r[6] == 6 &&
        $r[1] * $r[4] - $r[7] == 2 &&
        $r[2] + $r[5] - $r[8] == 6){

        $result = TRUE;
        echo "<pre>";
        echo print_r($r);
        echo "</pre>";

    } else {

        shuffle($r);

    }
}
```

If run that exact code on phpfiddle.org I get an instant result of that equation, but if I run on my locahost it gets to point of giving me a max execution timeout (120).

I believe my PC is not the problem, I have good specs, Core I5, 8GB ram, etc, So i believe that there is something wrong with my Wamp PHP configuration that its making the problem.

Funny enough, if i refresh the browser a couple of times it gives me the result at the speed of the click.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: With `shuffle` it is a matter of luck. But I don't think that it should take more than a second.

Comment: @Federico look for example: http://obs.com.do/testp.php that is on my webserver, not matter how many times i refesh the page, it gives me an instant result and the my webserver has less resources than my localhost.

Comment: shuffle is __random__.... you can't ever guarantee that a result that matches your math will be achieved..... a fast processor simply guarantees more randomisations before the timeout, it doesn't guarantee that you will achieve a valid result

Comment: @MarkBaker check my previous comment.

Comment: Your previous comment is irrelevant..... __random__ means __random__, it means __unpredictable__.... it could give you your valid result on the first shuffle, or it could take a million shuffles.... the only way that processing speed can make is increasing the number of randomisations per second, but it still cannot guarantee that you will get any result before the timeout

Comment: Have you even calculated how many possible combinations of 1-9 will give you a valid result?

Comment: @MarkBaker I understand, for illustration purposes: I CTRL+SHIFT+R on my webhost at least 40 times and each times it takes less than 2 seconds to give me a result. Now, 1 out of 40 it gives me a correct result on localhost.  Most of the time it goes beyond 120 seconds with this simple math problem, I truly believe that if it will be a random or shuflle problem, i would at least get 1 timeout on my webserver.

Comment: Two remarks: Firstly, there is a profiler which can be used to find out where your code spends its time. Secondly, if the maximum execution time presents a limit for your code, you just shouldn't run it inside a webserver but via CLI.